# Image to 2D Array then getImage from it after process

Tags: java, image

I am learn Image Processing Techniques and have some homework.
In my homework, which asked me to cover a RBG to gray image.
I've converted the images into 2D matrix, do somethings, and when i cover again from 2D matrix to image, some wrong happen.
This my code:

```
private static SampleModel samM;
public static int[][] imageToArrayPixel(File file) {
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
        Raster raster = img.getData();
        int w = raster.getWidth(), h = raster.getHeight();
        int pixels[][] = new int[w][h];
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                pixels[x][y] = raster.getSample(x, y, 0);
                System.out.print("  " + pixels[x][y]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        samM = raster.getSampleModel();

        return pixels;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static java.awt.Image getImage(int pixels[][]) {
    int w = pixels.length;
    int h = pixels[0].length;

    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(samM, new Point(0, 0));


    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pixels[i].length; j++) {
            if (pixels[i][j] > 128) {
                raster.setSample(i, j, 1, 255);
            } else {
                raster.setSample(i, j, 1, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    image.setData(raster);

    File output = new File("check.jpg");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", output);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}

public static java.awt.Image getImageWithRBG(Pixel pixels[][]) {
    int w = pixels.length;
    int h = pixels[0].length;

    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(samM, new Point(0, 0));
    int[] pixelValue = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
            pixelValue[0] = pixels[i][j].red;
            pixelValue[1] = pixels[i][j].blue;
            pixelValue[2] = pixels[i][j].green;
            raster.setPixel(j, i, pixelValue);
        }
    }

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(h, w, BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM);
    image.setData(raster);

    File output = new File("check.jpg");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", output);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int pixel[][] = imageToArrayPixel(new File("C:\\Users\\KimEricko\\Pictures\\1402373904964_500.jpg"));

    getImage(pixel);

}
```

This my image which i use to covert:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaYIc.jpg)
and here is the photo that I received after restoration:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE0gN.jpg)

I don't understand why the picture after restoring contains only 1/3 of the original photograph.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like there is a bug in getImageWithRBG, that 
raster.setPixel(j, i, pixelValue); 
should be
raster.setPixel(i, j, pixelValue);

setPixel and setSample have similar inputs: x then y

I don't know if there are other problems, that is just the first thing I noticed.

Comment: Thank for comment!